# memcache.so doesn't support in shared hosting?

Tags: curl, webserver, hosting

I have a function for products delivery. In this function, I got a service of delivery from JNE, Indonesian Delivery Service. The company gives me the needed file such as curulr with javascript, ajax and PHP,

When I debug it in NiagaHoster, one of web hosting service we have, it works fine. But when I run the program in iPage, it doesn't work.

So I ask the niagahoster team support for that problem. And they told me to ask iPage team support to enable the memcache.so. And one of technical support of iPage said that they doesn't support the memcache.so in shared hosting.

Anybody can help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For those confuse about the memcached extension and the memcache extension, the short story is that both of them are clients of memcached server, and the memcached extension offer more features than the memcache extension.

This is just an example of the Memcached.

```
<?php
  $m = new Memcached();
  $m->setOption(Memcached::OPT_BINARY_PROTOCOL, true);
  $m->setSaslAuthData("user-1", "pass");
?>
```